# How to put 127.0.0.1 ABOVE in /etc/resolv.conf with ubuntu + networkmanager + DHCP

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dhcp

Actually, on a ubuntu 16.04 server, my /etc/resolv.conf is :

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 213.186.33.99
search local
```

I want to put "nameserver 127.0.0.1" at the top.
I modified my network config file to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens3
iface ens3 inet dhcp
    dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1      <--- added this
```

but the nameserver 127.0.0.1 has been set at the bottom :

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 213.186.33.99
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search local
```

I modified /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf to ask to prepend 127.0.0.1 :

```
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
```

But now, the nameserver dynamically found by DHCP has disappeared :

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search local
```

So how can I have "nameserver 127.0.0.1" at the top AND the nameserver dynamically found by DHCP bellow ?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment line, the file is generated by [`resolvconf`(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/resolvconf.8.html). It is configured with [`resolvconf.conf`(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/resolvconf.conf.5.html):

> `name_servers`
>
> Prepend name servers to the dynamically generated list.  You
>   should set this to `127.0.0.1` if you use a local name server other
>   than libc.

And the options that affects the processing order:

> `interface_order`
>
> These interfaces will always be processed first.  If unset,
>    defaults to the following:-
>                      `lo lo[0-9]*`
>
> `dynamic_order`
>
> These interfaces will be processed next, unless they have a
>    metric.  If unset, defaults to the following:-
>                      `tap[0-9]* tun[0-9]* vpn vpn[0-9]* ppp[0-9]* ippp[0-9]*`

Comment: On ubuntu, there is no resolvconf.conf, the man pages for resolvconf do not tell how to prepend name servers. I found the file /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head that could help, but it is more for prepending comments.

Comment: These citations ARE from Ubuntu Manpages. `man resolvconf` has section `FILES` stating that `/etc/resolvconf.conf` is the configuration file for resolvconf. If it doesn't exist, defaults are used. Create the file, if missing.

Comment: My "man resolvconf" do not speak about your /etc/resolvconf.conf. On ubuntu website, I saw want you told, but it seems to come from an "open" version of resolvconf

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head,
put your the nameservers you want to prepend at its bottom,
using the usual syntax:
e.g.:

```
 ubuntu# cat head
 # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
 #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
 # 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
 # run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

 nameserver your.wanted.ip.here 
 nameserver another.extra.ip.here
```

Then, reload resolvconf:

```
ubuntu# systemctl restart resolvconf
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid setting this up the way you request will not work out as expected. The second nameserver will only be queried in case the first times out. If the response from the first server is NXDOMAIN the resolver stops as this is a valid reply.

In case you are looking for a solution that extends the valid responses with e.g. local dns entries the dns server on localhost needs to be configured to forward to another dns server after looking up its local entries and not matching a result.